# Alarm Manager won't work when the app is killed in the background and device is locked

Tags: android, alarmmanager, wakelock

I have been stuck in this situation for a long time...

I want to use the alarm manager to show notification at the specific time, and now it worked in the situation listed below:

1. when the app runs in the background, notification will be shown at the correct time, and no matter the device is locked or not.
2. after the app has been killed in the background, i will still get correct notification when device is not locked, but things turn wrong when the device is locked, i can't receive any notification.

Here's the code AlarmReceiver.java, all the needed permission has been added into AndroidManifest.xml already:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    WakeLocker.acquire(context);

    String action = intent.getAction();

    Log.d(TAG, action); //when app is killed and device is locked, no info is shown at the logcat

    if (ACTION_ALARM.equals(action)) {
        Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        vibrator.vibrate(2 * 1000);

        notify(context, "Jello!");
    }

    WakeLocker.release();
}

public static void alarm(Context context) {
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
    intent.setAction(ACTION_ALARM);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 5 * 1000, pi);
    } else {
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 5 * 1000, pi);
    }
}

private void notify(Context context, String msg) {
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
            context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
            new Intent(context, InfoActivity.class), 0);

    Notification notification =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.alarm))
                    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg))
                    .setContentText(msg)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setContentIntent(contentIntent).build();

    notificationManager.notify(1, notification);
}
```

Permissions added:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
```

Comment: Have you set correct permissions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found the solution, set flag named FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES to intent of the alarm, things will go right.
Here are the illustration in [Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES)

Comment: This will not make a difference since "This is the default behavior when FLAG_EXCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES is not set" as the link you are making reference says...

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue one day and found a solution online, which was wakelocking the phone when the broadcastreceiver was called.
So try creating this class, and calling `MyWakeLock.acquire()` when the broadcastreceiver gets called. You should also call `MyWakeLock.release()` when you are done executing whatever your alarm does.

```
package your.package.name;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.PowerManager;

public abstract class MyWakeLock {
    private static PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock;

    public static void acquire(Context c) {
        if (wakeLock != null) wakeLock.release();

        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) c.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK |
                PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP |
                PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE, MainActivity.APP_TAG);
        wakeLock.acquire();
    }

    public static void release() {
        if (wakeLock != null){
            wakeLock.release();
        }
        wakeLock = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have already created this class and acquire wakelock in onReceive() method, but it still not work... I was wondering the receiver is not fired when app is killed and device is locked

Comment: The you have permission problems

Comment: And i just found another situation, this code not work on my samsung galaxy s5, but worked on htc one x...

Comment: But i have already add the permission 'android.permission.WAKE_LOCK'

Comment: @user13 not work on samsung with android 5.0 and work on htc with 4.2

Comment: @Perroloco I have added the file

Comment: @Guomato are you sure it is not 6.0 on the Samsung device?

Comment: @user13 yes, samsung s5, not the latest one

Comment: @Guomato please check in Settings -> About phone -> Android version. Marshmallow is available for the Galaxy S5 for quite some time now.

Comment: Have you tried WakefulBroadcastReceiver?
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/WakefulBroadcastReceiver.html

Comment: I just figure it out... when the app first installed on my phone, there is a check box named “run automatically”, just check it and then it finally worked... Thank you all the same!

Answer (score 0):

i had this problem and finally found wrong targetSdkVersion is above 22 and no handle permission.
set targetSdkVersion 22 and worked ^_^