# AlarmManager not working in Android 8.1.0

Tags: java, android

My requirement is set `Notification` for specific time like user birthday or holiday

I am using **[AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager)** for scheduling notification using broadcast receiver

Code is working fine in `6.0` (even when app is killed,swiped from recent list) but not working on `Android 8.1.0` (Mf : Oppo)

Readed [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38442240/alarm-manager-wont-work-when-the-app-is-killed-in-the-background-and-device-is) and [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34378707/alarm-manager-does-not-work-in-background-on-android-6-0/34379987#34379987) and many answers but not find any helpfull 
any idea how to solve this issue

Here is my code

```
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    //creating a new intent specifying the broadcast receiver\

    Intent i = new Intent(this, HolidayBroadcast.class);
    i.putExtra("eventName",islamicHoliday.getEventName());
    i.putExtra("dateH", testTmp.getCalendar().getTimeInMillis());
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES);
    //creating a pending intent using the intent
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, new Random().nextInt(), i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


    //setting alarm
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        am.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,getTimeInMillis(), pi);
    }
    else
    {
        am.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, getTimeInMillis(), pi);
    }
```

Comment: refer this , https://stackoverflow.com/a/46305462/1848157 and https://medium.com/@iiro.krankka/its-time-to-kiss-goodbye-to-your-implicit-broadcastreceivers-eefafd9f4f8a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use workmanager as mentioned in link.It supports all api version and easy to use because it uses backward compatibility to API level 14

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager

https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/introducing-workmanager-2083bcfc4712

Comment: can you give some example of job sheduler i try but not working for shedule job after one year

Comment: but if you use work manager then there is no need to use of job scheduler.

Comment: ohk can you provide minimal example of workmanager which can helps to schedule jobs

Comment: You can find tutorials online and take a look at mentioned link:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50363541/schedule-a-work-on-a-specific-time-with-workmanager

Comment: What if I need to fire a task at specific time? Workmanager is not suitable for this (tasks can be deferred)

Answer (score 0):

If your task is time critical, WorkManager API is not recommended as for your alarm manager not working properly, on Android 8 use
`AlarmManager.setexactandallowwhileidle()`, to set exact time and allow wakeup notification while app is killed.